# handling error trying to set key of immutable and frozen object

Tags: react-native

i have the following object in a state:

App.js

```
    const data = {name: 'John', status:'employeed' };
    const [manager, updateManager] = useState(data);

    const updateStatus = async () =>{
        await service.setStatus(manager);
          
     }
```

setStatus does modify the manager directly, which I think is the source of the problem

service.js

```
       setStatus(manager){
           manager.status = 'employeed';
       }
```

so I modified the call to send a copy of the manager object and return a new object but still I get the error

```
     you tried to modify 'status' key of an immutable object.
```

here is my new change

App.js

```
   const updateStatus = async () =>{
        const g = await service.setStatus({...manager});
           updateManager(g);
     }
```

service.js

```
       setStatus(manager){
           manager.status = 'employeed';
          return manager;
       }
```

Comment: You're still modifying the state directly.  `setStatus(manager) { return {...manager, status: 'employeed'}; }` is how you would do it without changing the original. (Note that "employed" is how you would spell the status of having employment in English.)

Answer (score 0):

Why has this function to be async?

```
const updateStatus = async () =>{
    await service.setStatus(manager);
}
```

This return a new/updated object but it won‘t do any permanent changes.

```
 setStatus(manager){
    return {…manager,status: 'employeed'};
 }
```

Does the problem after your last changes persists?

You should pass a callback like this:

```
   const updateStatus = (manager) => {
        service.setStatus(()=> updateManager({
          ...manager,
          status: 'employeed'
   }));
```

Service.js

```
   setStatus(updateManager){
       updateManager(manager);
   }
```

Comment: setStatus is a promise so had to do it as async. Yes, after making my changes the error still persists, making me wonder if indeed i am sending a copy of the object.

Comment: setStatus has to be async, but inn your sample it isn't necessary at all.